# Stack Overflow Careers banner colors

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs

Why is it that in the image of the Stack Overflow Careers banner, the colors go from dark blue to red and the money goes from low to high?

[image: Stack Overflow Careers banner]

To me (I live in Europe) this seems like the small blue money stack is gold looking and the big red money stack is bronze looking. In the Euro coins, the bronze is the lowest value.

[image]

If the colors where turned around I think it would make more sense. Is this only a cultural thing and is bronze a high value coin in other cultures?

Comment: I think the colors are just supposed to be going from gray to orange, like the main Stack Overflow logo. The big stack of darker-colored coins in the last bar makes it a little harder to see, though.

Comment: I think @JohnFlatness is right; it's because of the SO logo. Regarding the color changes though; in American money, bronze is for the smallest denomination, and all other coins are usually silver. Gold colored coins are for 'special' dollars and other such things. So that is indeed a cultural thing. I'm sure it would be different in other countries as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The banner is simply following, from bottom to top, StackOverflow logo's colors.

Exactly 6 layers with the exact same colors.
[image]

Comment: woah! I would never have figured that out :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure they are going from blue to red. As far as I can see it is going from 
dark (monochrome) grey to a colorful red , which normally happens when the stack of money increases.. ;)

Comment: It just seems to me that the big stack is a stack of bronze coins, and in Euros they have the lowest value. And why would that specific color change happen if the stack of money increases?

Comment: It look to me as same coin in different ambience (background light).. Anyway you will have to ask the designer..

Comment: Let's hope the designer reads Meta StackOverflow :)