# banner: x2665 Your Job

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, advertising

About this banner:
[image]

`&x2665;` on a black background will render nothing. (black heart on black background)

Wouldn't it be '*nicer*' to be replaced with `&x2661;` (white heart) ?

Comment: That's the background of the IDE... Not really black either.. I see `#1E2714`.. Browsers backgrounds *are* usually white :P

Comment: Besides, it's not completely black; definitely a greenish cast to it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: a-ha! hidden for the eye, but not from machine... black-hat SEO :P

Comment: Is there ever going to be an add that [nobody will](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143130/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-careers-banner-with-the-dying-starfish) [complain about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163372/stackoverflow-careers-banner-colors)?

Comment: @Bart: why complain about complaining? if there's something that could be fixed/removed/improved people should be able to express themselves.

Comment: This is Meta. That place to complain about complaining. If you want to complain about that, Meta Meta would be the place. Other than that you can complain all you want. I just found it amusing.

Comment: @Bart: funny as hell, let's go to Meta Meta and continue this complaining business :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect. ♥ U+2665 BLACK HEART SUIT is not actually *black*. Unicode character names use the word “BLACK” to refer to the “foreground” or “ink” color of the text, not the color black.

(Whether or not that was the intent of the Unicode specification authors, it is certainly how every font renderer I have ever met does things, though I admit with the recent exception of these newfangled “emoji” characters, which should get off my lawn.)

When there are “BLACK” and “WHITE” versions of a character, the “BLACK” refers to a *solid* version whereas the “WHITE” one is ♡ *outlined*. If you copy the text of this answer and apply a white-on-black style, the “BLACK” heart will be white and the “WHITE” one will be a white outline.

Comment: very nice answer Kevin!